# Is there any rules of thumb for the relation of number of iterations and training size for lightgbm?

Tags: python, lightgbm

When I train a classification model using lightgbm, I usually use validation set and early stopping to determine the number of iterations.

Now I want to combine training and validation set to train a model (so I have more training examples), and use the model to predict the test data, should I change the number of iterations derived from the validation process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a similar problem in deep learning with Keras: I do it by using an early stopper and cross validation with train and validation data, and let the model optimize itself using validation data during trainings.

After each training, I test the model with test data and examine the mean accuracies. In the mean time after each training I save the `stopped_epoch` from `EarlyStopper`. If CV scores are satisfying, I take the mean of stopped epochs and do a full training (including all data I have) with the number of mean stopped epochs, and save the model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it is a little different. Number of epochs in deep learning means how many times you feed data into the training algorithm. Number of iterations in GBDT determines how many trees you are using, and more trees tend to over-fitting.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your comment, this is not comparable to the Deep Learning number of epochs because deep learning is usually stochastic.

With LGBM, all parameters and features being equals, by adding 10% up to 15% more training points, we can expect the trees to look alike: as you have more information your split values will be better, but it is unlikely to drastically change your model (this is less true if you use parameters such as `bagging_fraction` or if the added points are from a different distribution).

I saw people multiplying the number of iterations by 1.1 (can't find my sources sorry). 
 Intuitively this makes sense to add some trees as you potentially add information. Experimentally this value worked well but the optimal value will be dependent of your model and data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a well-established rule of thumb to do such estimate. As Florian has pointed out, sometimes people rescale the number of iterations obtained from early stopping by a factor. If i remember correctly, typically the factor assumes a linear dependence of the data size and the optimal number of trees. I.e. in the 10-fold cv this would be a rescaling 1.1 factor. But there is no solid justification for this. As Florian also pointed out, the dependence around the optimum is typically reasonably flat, so +- a bit of trees will not have a dramatic effect.

Two suggestions:

- do k-fold validation instead of a single train-validation split. This will allow to evaluate how stable the estimate of the optimal number of trees is. If this fluctuates a lot between folds- do not rely on such estimate :)
- fix the size of the validation sample and re-train your model with early stopping using gradually increasing training set. This will allow to evaluae the dependence of the number of trees on the sample size and approximate it to the full sample size.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated a dataset and I used it to test the effect of sample size on the best iteration selected.

I used `R`, the package `lightgbm` to run the `gbm`  and use code from the example `?gbm::gbm` to make the data.

I simulated 1.1 million observations, keeping the last 100,000 for testing.  I ran a gbm using from 25,000 to 1,000,000 observations for training, jumping by 25,000 each time.  The gbm parameters are shown below, but mostly an `early_stopping_round` of 100 and a `learning_rate` of 0.1.

That was a quick and dirty analysis.  It's possible the behavior observed will not be reproducible in other context.  I've notice on my side that playing with learning rate and early stopping round did affect the final graph.  However, I still think it's a least a beginning of an answer on the relation between sample size and optimal number of iteration.

the code:

```
## Prepare the data
set.seed(101) # for reproducibility
N <- 1100000
X1 <- runif(N)
X2 <- 2 * runif(N)
X3 <- ordered(sample(letters[1:4], N, replace = TRUE), levels = letters[4:1])
X4 <- factor(sample(letters[1:6], N, replace = TRUE))
X5 <- factor(sample(letters[1:3], N, replace = TRUE))
X6 <- 3 * runif(N)
X7 <- 3 * rnorm(N)
X8 <- sample(0:1, N, replace = T)
mu <- c(-1, 0, 1, 2)[as.numeric(X3)]
SNR <- 10 # signal-to-noise ratio
Y <- X1 ^ 1.5 + 2 * (X2 ^ 0.5) + X7 + X8 + X7*X8 + mu
sigma <- sqrt(var(Y) / SNR)
Y <- Y + rnorm(N, 0, sigma)
X1[sample(1:N,size=5000)] <- NA # introduce some missing values
X4[sample(1:N,size=3000)] <- NA # introduce some missing values
data <- data.frame(Y, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8)


## making a function that create the train and test set, run the gbm and extract the best iter
valid_n_iter <- function(maxN, data){
  
  dtrain <- lgb.Dataset(
    data = as.matrix(data[1:maxN,-1]),
    categorical_feature =  c("X3", "X4", "X5"), 
    label = data[1:maxN, 1]
  )
  lgb.Dataset.construct(dtrain) 
  
  dtest <- lgb.Dataset.create.valid(
    dtrain, 
    data = as.matrix(data[1000001:1100000,-1]),
    label = data[1000001:1100000, 1]
  )
  lgb.Dataset.construct(dtest) 
  
  valids <- list(train = dtrain, test = dtest)
  
  params <- list(num_leaves = 4,
                 learning_rate = 0.1,
                 objective = "regression", 
                 force_row_wise=TRUE,
                 nthread = 15
  )
  
  res_mod <- lgb.train(
    data = dtrain,
    params = params,
    nrounds = 20000,
    valids= valids,
    early_stopping_rounds = 100,
    verbose = 0
    #verbose = 1, eval_freq = 1
  )
  
  return(res_mod$best_iter)
}

## calling the function on mulitple N
iter_choice <- lapply(seq(25000, 1000000, 25000), valid_n_iter, data)
```

We can now plot the effect of N on best_iter

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(N=seq(25000, 1000000, 25000), best_iter=unlist(iter_choice)) , 
       aes(x=N, y=best_iter)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam")
```

[image]

We can see that the number of optimal iteration increase with an increase in sample size, however at some point the trend seems to plateau.  There also seems to be quite some variance with the optimal iteration chosen by the lightgbm algorithm.

I've also fitted a linear model for the first half of the trend (before the plateau).  Using the model, we can produce an example. Let's say we had 100,000 train observation and 100,000 test observations (so big N of 200,000), calculating the expected number iteration for the train test gives 453.  If we would have ran the whole dataset (200,000), the optimal number of iteration goes up to 611, a difference of 158. So, by doubling the sample, we saw an increase of 35% (158/453) of the number of iteration required to be optimal.

So to answer the question, I think it is safe to increase slightly the number of trees for analysis on full data sets, but there is still risk of overfitting in situations where most of the signal was already explained by your original model. Also, if you increase your sample size by X%, do not expect to be able to increase your number of trees by the same proportion, it's likely to be a lot less.